# Writing minimization problems as a linear programming problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have the following objective functions to be minimized

$$ \|Ax-b\|_{1} = \sum_{k} | a_{k}^Tx - b_{k} | $$

$$ \|Ax-b\|_{\infty} = \max_{k} | a_{k}^Tx - b_{k} | $$

How would you convert them to a linear program of the form:

$$\text{minimize}  \quad c^T z \qquad \text{subject to} \quad \hat{A} z \leq \hat{b}$$

where $z$ is unrestricted?

Answer (score 2):

For the first objective, introduce a new variable $y_k$ to represent $|a_k^T x - b|$, minimize $\sum_k y_k$, and include linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_k &\ge a_k^T x - b\\
y_k &\ge -a_k^T x + b
\end{align}

For the second objective, minimize $w$, and include linear constraints
\begin{align}
w &\ge a_k^T x - b\\
w &\ge -a_k^T x + b
\end{align}

I'll leave it to you to rewrite the $\ge$ constraints as $\le$ with constant right-hand sides.